# Replacing string in one variable with another

Tags: shell

I have a shell script like so -

```
codes=('B4036' 'B9002')

query=$(cat <<EOF
WITH claims AS 
(
   SELECT code, month, patient
   FROM lines
   WHERE code = 'proc_codes'
)
EOF
)

for i in "${codes[@]}"
do
  
  sql=$(echo $query | sed -e "s/proc_codes/$i/g")

done
```

When I print `sql`, I get

`WITH claims AS ( SELECT code, month, patient FROM lines WHERE code = '\''B4036'\'' )`

Why am I getting `'\''` around `proc_codes`? How do I get the above line to be -

`WITH claims AS ( SELECT code, month, patient FROM lines WHERE code = 'B4036' )`

Comment: Use codes=(B4036 B9002)

Comment: How do you print `sql`?

Comment: (Because I can't reproduce this with adding `echo "$sql"`)

Comment: @RamanSailopal That does not work. It outputs `WITH claims AS ( SELECT code, month, patient FROM lines WHERE code = B4036)`

Comment: You'll need to show your full script, including the shebang and how you're printing `sql`.  It looks like what you're seeing is just an artifact of the way you're printing.  Raman's suggestion should work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Raman's suggestion shouldn't make a difference, the quotes don't matter when creating the array as shown. The snippet works as-is for me.

Comment: I suppose when I say Raman's suggestion should "work", I mean that it shouldn't make any difference, and the code should continue to work.  I'm confused as to why it is apparently making a difference for the OP.  I suspect the shell being used is not a bourne shell, but it's not at all clear.